# Sitecore xConnect client certificates renewal

Tags: xconnect, paas, certificate

In our Sitecore 9.2 PaaS solution, we are using self-signed client certificates and have added the AppSetting `AllowInvalidClientCertificates=true` to all xConnect roles as well as the PRC, CD and CM server.

However, these certificates are about to expire, so we are wondering if we have to renew them or whether the setting AllowInvalidClientCertificates also enabled expired certificates to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should generate new cert and use it. It's not recommended to allow invalid client certs especially on Prod.

They are used for authentication so make sure client cert is valid and **AllowInvalidClientCertificates** is set to **false**.